# Why isn't my Bubble Sort working for inline assembly?

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, masm, inline-assembly

When I am trying to get my bubble sort to work by using numbers[] as the array and the MAX as the size of the array.

It seems to be giving me an error at the `xchg eax, [esi + 4]` saying an exception was thrown.

What is wrong?

```
extern "C" void bubble(int numbers[], int MAX) {


    int swap;

    _asm {
        push MAX
        push numbers

        push  ebp
        mov ebp, esp

        outerLoop :
        mov swap, 0
        mov   ecx, [ebp + 12]
        mov   esi, [ebp + 8]

        innerLoop :
        mov eax, [esi]
        cmp[esi + 4], eax
        jg nextStep
        xchg eax, [esi + 4]
        mov[esi], eax
        mov swap, 1

        nextStep:
        add esi, 4
        loop innerLoop

        cmp swap, 0
        jz loopEnd
        jnz outerLoop

        loopEnd :
        pop ebp


        add esp, 8
    }
}
```

Comment: it is unclear why you are pushing the two parameters in the inline rather than accessing the variables by name. But even if you were to keep them in there [EPB+0] is going to be the original EBP, [EBP+4] will be numbers and [EBP+8] will be MAX given that there is no return address on the stack. I recommend you step through with the debugger to determine these kind of bugs.

Comment: I kept that in mind and changed the code a bit, but still getting an exception error. I should leave [EBP+4] the same or should I replace it with the array called numbers?

Comment: Maybe you were looking for something like: http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/stackoverflow/bubble.c